# Displaying a list of pre-determined Geopoints

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

My app that I'm working on is mostly informational.  I have a MapView setup right now to use MyLocationOverlay to track where the user is.  I'm planning on having a list of coordinates for all of the buildings in the area.  If a user wants to see where it is on the map, they can open up my dialog, find the building in the list, click it, and have an overlay drawn for it.

I'm not sure the correct way to go about for this.  I already know how to create map overlays.  Would the best approach be to have a HashMap for latitudes and one for longitudes, and then go out and grab the coordinates manually to store into those maps?  By manually I mean having to find the coordinates myself and code them in by hand.  If I do this, what is the best way to find them manually?  I noticed by poking around in the javascript for Google Maps that there was a lat/lng value for the center of the map, but it would be a pain to do this for 100+ buildings.

Or should I be making a Google Maps query for the building and getting the coordinates for the overlay like that?  I have done some searching, but have no clue what to do if this is the best way to do it.  I was also thinking that I might run into some query limit by doing it this way rather than having the coordinates programmed directly into my app.

I'm not a beginner with Android or programming, but my data structures knowledge is a bit rusty.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated (maybe I'm approaching the whole thing wrong).